# CSS "all" Transition is not working

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions, css-animations

I need help my css transition because it seems to be not working at all. Here's my css code. Do you you think that I missed something?

```
   /*header navigation in homepage*/
    .home header#main-header {
        position: absolute;
        top: auto !important;
        bottom: 0px !important;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
        transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
    }
    .home header#main-header.et-fixed-header {
        position: fixed !important;
        top: 0px !important;
        bottom: auto !important;
        transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
    }
    /*end of header navigation in homepage*/
    /*full width slider in homepage*/
    .fs{
      position:absolute;
      top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;
      z-index: 10;
      background-position:bottom;
      background-size: inherit;
    }
    .home #page-container{margin-top:100vh !important;}
    /*end of full width slider in homepage*/
```

Oh, here's a link for the website --> http://concept1.mystudioengine.site/
What I'm trying to do is header nav bar supposed to have an animation on scroll. Please help. Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: You can't transition from `absolute` to `fixed`. Give us a working demo of the problem in the post itself please. We need a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: I was trying to copy this site's header nav's animation http://www.divithemeexamples.com/Star-Cafe-Divi-Child-Theme/

Answer (score 0):

First, is not a good idea use all in this case, add a transition for each specific property that you want to animate.

So, there are some properties and values that you can't animate, like `top: auto` to `top: 0px`.

But animate properties like `top`, is not recommended for performance questions, I suggest you to read [this post about achieving 60 FPS animations](https://medium.com/outsystems-experts/how-to-achieve-60-fps-animations-with-css3-db7b98610108#.ub385aiw3), and [about Critical Rendering Path](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwic5aOR1czSAhWGG5AKHemQAucQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fweb%2Ffundamentals%2Fperformance%2Fcritical-rendering-path%2F&usg=AFQjCNEwIG_rvxlunFwdbZ8D47Q6KHBllw&sig2=cfmhcMJgMUjpfMs0AMRfOQ&bvm=bv.149397726,d.Y2I).

In this case, the best option is to use something like this to animate your header for a fixed position:

```
/*header navigation in homepage*/
.home header#main-header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    transition: transform 3s ease-in-out;
}
.home header#main-header.et-fixed-header {
    position: fixed;
    transform: translateY(0);
}
/*end of header navigation in homepage*/
```